# PHP MySQLi mysqli_fetch_array Returns multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to create a single dimensional enumerated array of a single column of data.

```
$dbc_db_filenames       = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$query_db_filenames     = "SELECT file FROM transactions_tb WHERE file != ''";
$get_db_filenames       = mysqli_query($dbc_db_filenames, $query_db_filenames);
$array_rows             = array();
while($rows             = mysqli_fetch_array($get_db_filenames, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $array_rows = $rows;
    echo "<br /><br /><pre>";
    print_r($array_rows);
    echo "</pre><br />";
}
mysqli_close($dbc_db_filenames);
```

Currently it's returning multiple arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2_20140908131122368017.jpg
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2_20140908130449345689.jpg
)
```

I want it to return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
    [1] => 2_20140908131122368017.jpg
    [2] => 2_20140908130449345689.jpg
)
```

I'm comparing a directories contents with the filename that's stored in the database on upload. To get the directories contents into an array I'm using this code:

```
$list = scandir(UPLOAD_PATH);
echo '<br /><br /><pre>';
print_r($list);
echo '</pre><br />';
```

Which returns the kind of array I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
    [1] => 2_20140908131122368017.jpg
    [2] => 2_20140908130449345689.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
while($rows             = mysqli_fetch_array($get_db_filenames, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $array_rows[] = $rows[0];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_rows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Yeah..that makes it worse. It creates tons of array sets: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
        )

)



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908131122368017.jpg
        )

)



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908130612381070.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908131122368017.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2_20140908130449345689.jpg
        )

)

Comment: @Micah You just need to change it to `$array_rows[] = $rows[0];`. And initializing an empty array before the loop is always a good idea.

Comment: @Micah jeroen is right, in that case try $array_rows[] = $rows[0]; this will do... and please put print_r($array_rows); outside the while loop. _ __!

Comment: You BOTH ROCK! Between this: $array_rows[] = $rows[0]; ... and this: put print_r($array_rows); outside the while loop ... It did it. I've been hunting this down a couple hours now. Thanks for the super fast help :)

Comment: This is my first question on here and I don't know protocol. Should I go ahead and mark this as the answer..let one of you update with a fully done answer or post the update myself and mark it? Thank you!

Comment: I just edited my answer above, it was a minor mistake. You can mark it now, I think

Comment: Hmmm..this omits the very first row from the result set. How can I show that too?

Comment: Ok..just figured it out. When I removed this line: $get_db_filenames       = mysqli_query($dbc_db_filenames, $query_db_filenames); .. it solved it. This moved the internal pointer forward to the second result.